# Photoshop javascript send keystroke

Tags: javascript, sendkeys, photoshop-script

I would like some help regarding a javascript using it in Photoshop. I converted a PS action into a java script and it is working fine, but I would like to modify it a bit. The PS script contains printing, but when the script gets there, an alert window stops the script and waiting for user input. What I need is that the javascript sends a keystroke (ENTER) to accept the alert - after this eveything is goes on and working fine.

Please note that I would like to have this specific solution and not interested in any other method. (I tried everything what one can find on the internet and either of them work, nor I am at the level to fix those code.)

I put here the **part** of the code I think needs to me modified:

****part of the code****

```
// Print    
  function step25(enabled, withDialog) {        
    if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)      
      return;     
    var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);    
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();    
    desc1.putBoolean(cTID('PstS'), true);    
    desc1.putEnumerated(cTID('Inte'), cTID('Inte'), cTID('Clrm'));    
    executeAction(cTID('Prnt'), desc1, dialogMode);    
  };
```

*****  **CODE STOPS HERE 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSY6D.png)
ENTER key needs to be send here**  *****

```
// Save
  function step26(enabled, withDialog) {
if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
  return;
var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
desc2.putInteger(cTID('EQlt'), 12);
desc2.putEnumerated(cTID('MttC'), cTID('MttC'), cTID('None'));
desc1.putObject(cTID('As  '), sTID("JPEGFormat"), desc2);
desc1.putPath(cTID('In  '), new File("/c/PHOTO_BOOT/PS_Temporary_Save/Almost_There.jpg"));
desc1.putBoolean(cTID('Cpy '), true);
executeAction(cTID('save'), desc1, dialogMode);
```

****code continues...****

Thank you for your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
```

with

```
var dialogMode = DialogModes.NO;
```